# How to get the svg text element in rectangle with particular width and height?

Tags: php, svg

I have been trying to get the SVG  with rectangular shape with text element with it in a particular width and height.

I have the output values for top and left for hello is top:22left:175
 and for test is top:195left:116 with these values how to get the desired output svg file

IF i give x and y zero to text element it doesn't start from corner of the rectangle

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" version="1.0">
        <rect style="fill:none;stroke:#373435;stroke-width:2.08346" width="500" height="500"></rect>
          <g id="0.8354780427180231" transform="translate(0 0 219 109)">
         <text fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="219" y="109" text-anchor="middle" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1">        
      <tspan dy="0" x="49%">Hello</tspan>
    </text>
    </g>
    <g id="0.2922376764472574" transform="translate(0 0 207 109)">
     <text fill="#000000" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" x="207" y="109" text-anchor="middle" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine" data-textcurve="0" data-itemzoom="1 1"><tspan dy="0" x="49%">Tetst</tspan>
      </text>
        </g>

</svg>`
```

Desired output of SVG file should be like this:

[image]

But my output like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0voD3.png)

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried so far and any relevant research. As the question stands now it is too broad.

Comment: What i ve tried is creating svg dynamically in php with the output values. the above code one i have created

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do here?

```
transform="translate(0 0 219 109)"
```

The `translate()` transform function takes two parameters `x` and `y`, not four.

In addition, you are supplying both an `x` and `y` attributes for the `<text>` element **and** you are also giving the `<tspan>` `x` and `dy` parameters.

Because of all that, I am unsure what you are actually trying to achieve.  If you are just trying to position the two pieces of text on the page, then you really only need just one of those techniques, not all three.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd" version="1.0">
  <rect style="fill:none;stroke:#373435;stroke-width:2.08346" width="500" height="500"></rect>

  <text fill="#000000"
        x="219" y="109"
        text-anchor="middle" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine">Hello</text>

  <text fill="#000000"
        x="207" y="180"
        text-anchor="middle" font-size="90.75" font-family="Twine">Tetst</text>
    
</svg>`
```

Comment: how to position the text to left like the image

Comment: please check with my desired output file

Comment: The `x` and `y` attributes of the `<text>` element, set the position. To move the text to the left, decrease the `x` attribute.

Comment: I have the output elements as top:22 left:175 how to design with these elements for the text

Comment: `top` and `'left` do not work with SVG elements like `<text>`. You need to use `x` and `y` in this case.

Comment: IF i give x and y zero to text element it doesnt start from corner of the rectangle

Comment: That's because `x` and `y` specify the start of the *baseline* of the text. Not the top left of the text.